# Convert sha256 string to number - Java

Tags: java

The code below in JS converts a Hash to a number, but I tried to write a similar code in Java and both return different results.

What's the best way to get the same result shown in JS using Java?

**JS**

```
const hash = "806abe48226985c5fb0e878792232204d74643e190e25a4c20a97748d52b191c"
console.log(parseInt(hash, 16) % 11);
```

**Result:**
2

**Java**

```
 String hash = "806abe48226985c5fb0e878792232204d74643e190e25a4c20a97748d52b191c";
    BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hash, 16);
    System.out.println(bigInt.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(11)).intValue());
```

**Result:**
4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct value is `4`. The result from the JavaScript snippet is incorrect, as the number is too large to be represented accurately. Use `BigInt` instead.

```js
const hash = "806abe48226985c5fb0e878792232204d74643e190e25a4c20a97748d52b191c"
console.log(Number.isSafeInteger(parseInt(hash, 16))); // do not use this!
console.log((BigInt('0x' + hash) % 11n).toString());
```

Comment: I understood perfectly, I understood that there is a failure in the logic applied in the JS due to the limit. But if you want, it is possible to represent exactly the same result found in JS by truncating the value in some way in Java.

Comment: I understand that it is not correct, but the main code runs with this logic, and today what I need is to replicate this in Java. Later I can check to adapt both to the correct way.

Comment: @wls261552 You could use `System.out.println((int)(new BigInteger(hash, 16).doubleValue() % 11));`, but I don't see how this would be useful.

Comment: Worked perfectly. In fact it is an error, but these wrong calculations have already been used to generate some results and I needed to replicate even if that way. As soon as possible I equalize both for the correct calculation. Thanks